# What are references that are not tags or branch heads?

Tags: git

When I do `git ls-remote` I get something like:

```
679ba3cdb7201763c0a243e0169a7f8fd210b5b1        HEAD
045b31588f934722cd9df1570987ed84b6e9b070        refs/heads/feature/proto-version-update
7b278f052ab47c49a6c1ac9bd12d05b72a4af584        refs/heads/iml
679ba3cdb7201763c0a243e0169a7f8fd210b5b1        refs/heads/master
52dc74d4b4775d7e24534b87908fb5efcd6d3118        refs/pull-requests/14/from
453f675541cd12e01cb05a7f8a63fadfb26e62fa        refs/pull-requests/14/merge
```

I know what the last two entries like `refs/pull-requests/14/merge` are *for* - they're created by our central repo (Stash) to manage pull requests. (I have no intention of modifying them, I'm just curious and want to peek under the hood, mainly to understand git a little better on the way)

But I don't understand what they *are*. They don't appear to be branches or tags (adding `--heads --tags` to the command hides them), and fetch doesn't pull them. How can I fetch them locally so that I can inspect them further?

**What are they? How can I inspect them?**

(The [Git references](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-Git-References) and the [`git ls-remote`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote) documentation mentions only heads, tags and remotes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer to part of my question:

As described in the [documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#CRTB), `git fetch` only fetches references specified in the `remote.<repository>.fetch` config parameter. I don't see them because I have:

```
$ git config --get remote.origin.fetch
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

Explicitly running `git fetch origin +:refs/pull-requests/14/merge` does pull it locally.